# Inconsistent file paths in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following view:

```
class UserProfileView(APIView):
    permissions_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    def get(self, request):
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        serializer = UserPrivateSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The following Model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pp = models.ImageField(blank=True)
```

and the following serializer:

```
class UserPrivateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

The following urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/', UserProfileView.as_view())
]
```

I response I get is:

```
{
    "pp": "/media/WIN_20190423_18_50_32_Pro.jpg"
}
```

when I expect:

```
{
    "pp": "localhost:8000/media/WIN_20190423_18_50_32_Pro.jpg"
}
```

I know it's not a model or serializer issue because I have other views that use the same model and serializer where it returns the full path.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
class UserProfileView(APIView):
    permissions_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    def get(self, request):
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        serializer = UserPrivateSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context())
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

the key is add `context=self.get_serializer_context()` to you serializer.

Comment: I get the error saying, 'UserProfileView' object has no attribute 'get_serializer_context'

Comment: try `serializer = UserPrivateSerializer(user, context={'request': request})`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out all I do was to add `context={"request": request}` to the serializer.